# Why Laravel Eloquent puts wrong data in Database?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, sql-update

```
@component('mail::message')
# Hello from our blog

Your password recovery code:

<?php
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    $characters = '0123456789';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    App\Models\Registration::where('email', '=', $_SESSION['email'])->update(['recovery_code' => $randomString]);
    echo $randomString;
    
?><br><br>

Blog
@endcomponent
```

So this is my recovery email (it's blade.php, like an html that is sent by email).
I generate random string and I update my database where email is current email: I set recovery_code value to $randomString and then I echo it, so that receiver would get his code(it's all in email, remember?).

But when I check the MySQL database it is filled with different code than the one I get from email. But also recovery code from database is always the same length as in the email. The code in database IS UPDATING, BUT it gives the wrong data.

I use mailtrap.io to send virtual messages.

Model code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Registration extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'registrations';
}
```

Comment: Laravel Eloquent is very widely used. It's extremely unlikely that it is putting incorrect data in to the database. It is much more likely that you are passing it incorrect data.

Comment: What does `$_SESSION['email']` contain? Why do this in a view file and not a controller or model?

Comment: You think if I do it in controller it would work?

Comment: Would you be able to share your models' code? What is the name of your table?

Comment: @Imersin Try it again after adding this line to your model: `protected $fillable = [ 'recovery_code' ];`

Comment: @Arash didn't help